# How can I simplify my nested sinatra routes?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I require nested subdirectories in my sinatra app, how can I simplify this repetitive code?

```
# ------------- SUB1 --------------
get "/:theme/:sub1/?" do
    haml :"pages/#{params[:theme]}/#{params[:sub1]}/index"
end

# ------------- SUB2 --------------
get "/:theme/:sub1/:sub2/?" do
    haml :"pages/#{params[:theme]}/#{params[:sub1]}/#{params[:sub2]}/index"
end

# ------------- SUB3 --------------
get "/:theme/:sub1/:sub2/:sub3/?" do
    haml :"pages/#{params[:theme]}/#{params[:sub1]}/#{params[:sub2]}/#{params[:sub3]}/index"
end

# ------------- SUB4 --------------
get "/:theme/:sub1/:sub2/:sub3/:sub4/?" do
    haml :"pages/#{params[:theme]}/#{params[:sub1]}/#{params[:sub2]}/#{params[:sub3]}/#{params[:sub4]}/index"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use splat parameters:

```
get "/:theme/*/?" do
  haml "pages/#{params[:theme]}/#{params[:splat].to_s}/index".to_sym  
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Though should be `haml : "`

Comment: The `to_sym` method will convert the string to a symbol. I've updated the answer.